# Android Localising for different languages

Tags: android, xml, localization

This probably sounds like a stupid Q so apologies. I'm trying to set my app up for different languages and know that I need new folders such as values-fr for French with appropriate strings.xml files etc. etc.

However, my existing values folder has 4 files in there 2 of which are unaffected by language changes (dimes.xml and styles.xml). Do I need to copy these into the new language values-fr (or whatever) folder or will the app find them in the regular values folder?

My thanks.

Comment: You really need to read [“Providing Alternative Resources”](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). As an addition, please read [“Non-translatable Strings”](http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings) as well.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to put dimes.xml or styles.xml in values-fr or whatever , you can put in on values and app will find them, or for dimens.xml you can put in values-mdpi, values-hdpi ... .